# I don't know is that virus or no

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

When I open the Samsung galaxy tab it keeps downloading app systems which some of them are inappropriate and I can't delete them and also it keeps making shortcuts of it.Also there is a problem that prevents me from doing something.Something called GPS speed keeps spamming my screen:"Unfortunately,GPS speed has stopped.
I need help!

Comment: Have you installed any apps recently for this to happen?? If yes try uninstalling them. Or you can even consider a `Factory Reset` at worst case ....

Comment: i can do anything to return my tablet back.yes i got baited but instead of downloading the main app they downloaded this malware or virus which wrecks my tablet

Comment: luckily i don't have info on this tab so what is factory reset?

Comment: It seems obvious that you didn't flash properly. How and which ROM did you flash?

Comment: I used GT-N800.

Comment: From where did you download it?

Comment: From a website.I tried to download it with sammobile but i couldn't because it keeps saying u need membership and i already joined the free membership

Comment: Do you have a trusted link?

Comment: I don't have...you can google it. The are definitely some working links out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factory reset your device. Factory reset restores your device to the state it was in when you purchased your device, i.e. it'll wipe all your apps & data. For instructions on how to factory reset your device, follow this link: https://www.technipages.com/galaxy-tab-4-hard-reset

Comment: Did you properly factory reset your phone?

Comment: I factory reset a lot but it didn't work.I tried flashing it but now after the flash when i open the samsung i get stuck with the samsung logo